# Embed timestamp in video file using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webcam, timestamp

I'm trying to record a video from the webcam using ffmpeg, while saving the exact timestamp in the video format so that I can later match it with other recorded videos:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -ts abs -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -copyts ts_test.mkv
```

This however seems to mess up the duration of the video. Using `ffprobe`:

```
$ ffprobe ts_test.mkv                                                           
...
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'ts_test.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 428390:10:05.90, start: 1542204570.100000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:2:2), yuv422p, 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
      DURATION        : 428390:10:05.900000
```

So, although the start time is listed as the current epoch, the duration is now also set to the time passed since 1970 (~428390 hours), which obviously messes with most video players.

What is the correct way to record the timestamp using ffmpeg?